# Compilation error creating an adapter in a fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment which contains several views including a ListView. In order to set the adpater for the listview, I thought I'd recycle some old (working) code I'd previously written in an *activity*. The code in the activity looked something like this:

```
adapter = new myadapter(
            this,
            list_of_things,
            R.layout.custom_row_view,
            new String[] {"label","day","time"},
            new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text3, R.id.text2}
            );
```

Where myadapter was a method within my activity's class, defined like so...

```
public class myadapter extends SimpleAdapter {
```

Now I tried to put the same myadapter method inside my fragment class and called

```
adapter = new myadapter(
            this,
            list_of_things,
            R.layout.custom_row_view,
            new String[] {"label","day","time"},
            new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text3, R.id.text2}
            );
```

but now I get a compile time error:

```
The constructor MyTestFragment.myadapter(MyTestFragment, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, int, String[], int[]) is undefined
```

I don't know whether my bug could be some minor typo - or whether its something more fundamental, like not being allowed adapters within fragments.

Comment: post myadapter implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `getActivity()` instead of this in myadapter

```
adapter = new myadapter(
            getActivity(),
            list_of_things,
            R.layout.custom_row_view,
            new String[] {"label","day","time"},
            new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text3, R.id.text2}
            );
```

because the `this` in myadapter is referencing your `Fragment` and not your `Activity`.